# How can I use something like (input == '\n') to determine when to stop accepting user input?

Tags: java, loops, input, char

I have to convert an infix operation to a postfix one, however the infix operation must be inputted as one character per line. So instead of inputting something like this: 3-2, you would need to input something like this:

```
3
-
2
```

I had an idea of using =='\n' to determine whether the inputted character is a next line function so that would determine the end of the equation, but it doesn't work. I tried replacing it with a different character such as =='e', and that works perfectly. What can I do to fix this?

```
   String string = "";
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   boolean flag = true;
   while (flag==true)
   {
       char charIn = input.next().charAt(0);
       string = string + charIn;
       if (charIn=='e') //inputting 'e' gives me my desired result
       {
           flag = false;
       }
   }
   //code that passes string to InfixToPostfix method and prints out the answer. this part works fine
```

Comment: You can not check a `char` for "\n" because a `char` is only one character.

Comment: Ending with a `=` sign would be better than a new line.

Comment: Your example shows 3 lines, so 3 strings, each one would have a newline with it. It is really not clear how you want users to input data here....

Comment: @Zephyr i replaced char with String but it still doesn't work

Comment: @kks21199 it's an exercise for school, so i have to follow the given specs

Comment: You did not specify this was for a school assignment or include your limitations.

Comment: @GhostCat the input should be able to handle more than 3 lines depending on how long the equation, that's why i thought of using while (true)...i tried while (input.hasNext()) too but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify that this was a school assignment or that you had certain restrictions, so this answer is admittedly a shot in the dark.

I would recommend using a `StringBuilder` within a loop and reading `nextLine()` instead of simply `next()`. This allows you to determine if the entry was empty (ie: the enter key was pressed without entering a character).

Also, we should allow the user to enter more than one character anyway (what happens when they try to enter `22` as a number). Abandoning the `char` type allows for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag) {

        // Capture all characters entered, including numbers with multiple digits
        String in = input.nextLine();

        // If no characters were entered, then the [ENTER] key was pressed
        if (in.isEmpty()) {
            // User is done adding characters; exit the loop
            flag = false;
        } else {

            // Otherwise, get the text entered and add it to our final string
            string.append(in);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Final String: " + string);
}
```

Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Reading full lines into a String will also help with numbers that have more than one digit. However, collecting all input in a StringBuilder does not help much. For Postfix operations you will want to push numbers onto a stack and when an operation comes along, pop top 2 numbers, apply operation and push result onto stack again.

Comment: I updated the code sample to exit the loop when the [ENTER] key is pressed, as I believe that was the OP's original intent.

Comment: @Ridcully - thank you; I added that explanation to the code :)

Comment: i'm still quite new to stack overflow so i apologize for leaving out some details. i tried using a stringbuilder and .isEmpty() to check for a next line and this worked! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @cccc - I did just update the code again to allow more than one character to be added to the `String`. This is because your user may enter `23` as a number and the original `char` would ignore the `3`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. Reading just the first character has its limitations.

```
String string = "";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean flag = true;
while (flag==true)
{
     String nextLine = input.nextLine();
     char charIn;

     if(nextLine.length() > 0) {
       charIn = nextLine.charAt(0); //This is bad idea as you can only operate on single digit numbers
       System.out.println("charIn = " + charIn);;
       string = string + charIn;
     }
     else
          flag = false;
}
```